# Convert NSDictionary values to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary in which the values are of different types, but need to be converted to strings and put back into the original NSDictionary. I have the following so far:

```
for (id key in myDictionary) {
    id value = [myDictionary objectForKey:key];
    value = (NSString *)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value];
}
```

However this is not working - when I print out the type of each value afterwards, they remain the same as before. Can anyone advise?

Comment: [myDictionary description];

Comment: @LalKrishna Doesn't this convert the entire dictionary to string? I only need the values to be strings

Comment: I think only `value = [NSString stringWithFomat:@"%@",value]` will do the trick.

Comment: @iPeter this is what OP has in code sample, and its not what they want.

Comment: String * valueStr = [value description];??

Comment: Could you pls provide sample dictionary values?

Comment: what do you mean by print out the type afterwards? do you expect that after converting it will change the datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an object into a format string with `%@` the objects `- (NSString *)description` gets called. If you have not overriden this method in your subclass it will print the class name and objects memory address by default. Also, the cast is not needed.

To solve your issue you can either provided custom implementation of `description` method in your classess, or create your own protocol with a `- (NSString *)toString` method and implement it where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!! You will get good idea! If you want clear option, Could please provide sample dictionary values?

```
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [myDictionary setObject:@"Vignesh" forKey:@"name"];
    [myDictionary setObject:@(10) forKey:@"rollnum"];
    [myDictionary setObject:@(429) forKey:@"mark"];
    [myDictionary setObject:@(85.8) forKey:@"average"];

    for (id key in myDictionary) {
        NSLog(@"Befor Convert Value %@ - Class %@",[myDictionary objectForKey:key], [[myDictionary objectForKey:key] class]);
        NSString *value = [NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myDictionary objectForKey:key]]];
        NSLog(@"After Value %@ - Class %@ - Length %@",value, [value class],@(value.length));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of description method, credit @Losiowaty

```
//quick way to create dictionary
NSDictionary * d = @{@"keyA":@(22),@"keyB":[UIView new],@"keyC":@"valueC"};

//create mutable dictionary for new values
NSMutableDictionary * md = [@{}mutableCopy];

//loop through all keys
for (NSString * key in d.allKeys){

    //set value
    md[key]=[d[key] description];

}

NSLog(@"d is %@", d);
NSLog(@"md is %@", md);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
for (id key in myDictionary) {
   if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
       NSString * value = [[myDictionary objectForKey:key] stringValue];
   }
}
```

Comment: If there are classess not respondingn to `stringValue` in thie collection the code will crash.

Comment: if you have other object then make sure it perform type checking

Comment: You check the type of `key` - it has nothing to do with the type of value under that key.